# systemd: network-online.target is reached before network.target

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I observed the following in the Archlinux installation ISO:

There is a systemd target definition in

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/network-online.target
```

containing:

```
[Unit]
Description=Network is Online
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Documentation=http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget
After=network.target
```

Now when I boot up the ISO in QEMU and call journalctl, I see:

```
[...]
Aug 26 14:13:05 archiso systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
[...]
Aug 26 14:13:56 archiso systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
[...]
```

How can this happen? I believed that the

```
After=network.target
```

would ensure that the target "Network is Online" is reached after "Network".

Comment: May be you have to read [this](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget). :)

Comment: Hey taliezin, I've read that document before posting here but I didn't find the answer to my question there. Generally speaking, my question is: How can a target A be reached before a target B if A contains a `After=B.target` line?

Comment: @taliezin I also don't understad how the article you linked answers this question.

Comment: @jan I thought it would help: `network.target` has very little meaning during start-up... It's primary purpose is for ordering things properly at _shutdown_: since the shutdown ordering of units in systemd is the reverse of the startup ordering, any unit that is order After=network.target can be sure that it is stopped before the network is shut down if the system is powered off...  Also I didn't post it as an answer and as I read all text it explains why it may happen: `After=B.target`.

Comment: @taliezin I don't see any reason why the targets should be reached in the wrong order. Therefore if you do see it in the documentation, please make a proper answer.